# How do I classify a law?

Tags: government, law

I have this idea in my head where all the books of law in this large star-system empire are stored in some sort of mechanical library. You can access it by going through categories. For instance:

Laws made on 4/22/2020 -> Intergalactic laws -> Criminal laws -> Substantive laws -> Definitions of illegal actions -> Arson

There are already some classifications for laws, i.e. substantive laws, domestic laws, criminal laws, etc. However, I want a full-fledged hierarchy, which is intuitive and easily navigatable for the public to use. Think the twelve tablets of Rome and you're on the right track.

Does anyone have an idea as to what kind of a hierarchy would be the most concise and efficient way to navigate laws?

Comment: Perhaps you might find it educational to do some research into library classification systems such as the Library of Congress classification or the Dewey Decimal. Otherwise you are only trying to reinvent the wheel and a square wheel at that. The devlopment of library cataloguing systems have already done the heavy lifting. You can benefit from following their example.

Comment: Note that modern online searching and computing means that we typically search using words and *tags* for suitable books.  We have to a certain extent bypassed the formal hierarchical organization of systems.  It's hard to imagine an empire with *intergalactic* laws relying on something as crude as a hierarchy of subjects when searched.  It's also incomprehensible why they'd be using a *mechanical* system of any kind when they'd certainly be using a computerized system for speed and compactness and the vastly increased flexibility for searching this gives.

Comment: @StephenG Even with strictly analogue methods, people will come up with their own ways of organizing. My mother works in estate planning; she has a spiral-bound law reference that some patient soul compiled from a variety of different statutes relevant to that field. It doesn't matter that *formally*, some of them are under section 30 and some under section 40, they're all in the same book.

Comment: @StephenG I was thinking computers are restricted for use only by the government, like _Dune_, but laxer, as in you can use computers, but only trusted people can. (maybe I'm misinterpreting _Dune_?)

Comment: @a4android Thanks, this is really helpful. I really like the Library of Congress system, so maybe I'll use the law section of that (albeit with some minor modifications and additions.)

Comment: Most countries have a Commercial Code, a Civil Code, a Penal Code, a Code of Procedure (usually divided into Commercial, Civil and Penal procedure). Plus of course a Construction Code, and Electrical Code etc.

Comment: In *Dune* my understanding is that AI ("thinking machines") were forbidden but I don't recall "dumb" computers being actually forbidden.  At the time it was written the concept of a personal computer was itself basically sci-fi and the idea we'd all carry phones linked to the entire internet's knowledge base was practically unimaginable for most.  Isn't Battlestar Galactica based on a culture than doesn't allow AI but does allow "dumb" computers ?  I'd think more in those terms for plausible sci-fi.  No computers would basically make intergalactic tech impossible, IMO.